# How do I install openjdk 17?

Tags: java

Firstly I have tried to get it from snap via `sudo snap find openjdk` and after finding a snap for version 18 I have to proceed by `sudo snap install...`. Then I tried to start my program which needs java, but there was an error and the error is pointing to Ubuntu's OpenJDK 11.

So I have proceeded with `dpkg --list`, to get the exact name of the 18 for installation, but I haven't found it. Is there a need for any refreshment, that `dpkg` loads it?

As I still had 17s tar, I followed [Openjdks installation guide](https://openjdk.org/install/), it just extracts the files but no installation. So there is no need to install it? My program still points to version 11 and if I use `dpkg --list` it's not there either.

Comment: `dpkg` doesn't show snaps.